# C++ multidimensional map: How to acces 'inner' maps?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional map. Lets say:

```
std::map<std::string, 
    std::map<std::string, 
        std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string>>>> my_map;
```

My question is: What is the proper way to get access to the 'inner' maps (the objects)? I do not talk about the values. I know they can be accessed via

```
my_map["key1"]["key2"]....
```

I mean the size for example. How do I get the size of the second map. Is this the right way to do it?:

```
my_map.begin()->second.size()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the proper way to get access to the 'inner' maps?

There isn't *the* inner map. There are *lots* of inner maps. `m_map["key1"]` is one inner map, `m_map["key2"]` is another inner map. For every key on the outer map, there is a new inner map. These maps are not related to each other - they have the same type, that's it.

`my_map.begin()->second.size()` will print the size of the inner map corresponding to the *first* key, in the same way that `m_map["key1"].size()` will print the size of the inner map corresponding to `"key1"`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but please note, that I used the plural in my question. Nevertheless it is good to point it out, to make it really clear for anybody else. I also take it, that `my_map.begin()->second.size()` is the proper way to do it, if I do not know the keys.

Comment: @kiigass Is the proper way to do *what*? You can't get the size of *the* second map, there isn't one of them. It's *a* way to get the size of one of the maps, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the inner `map` exists, or you intend to create it you can do:

```
my_map["key1"].size();
```

Or for the most interior `map`:

```
my_map["key1"]["key2"].size();
```

If you *don't* know if the interior `map` exists and you *don't* want to create it you'll have to use [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find):

```
const auto it = my_map.find("key1");
const auto size = it = my_map.end() ? 0 : it->size();
```

For the most interior `map` that would be:

```
const auto it = my_map["key1"].find("key1");
const auto size = it = my_map["key1"].end() ? 0 : it->size();
```